# how to search a particular word or entry inside a sub folder in a repository on github

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, search, github

I am just looking for an example ( the correct command to fire in the advance search at github ) about  searching a word **inside a folder** of a particular repository. I guess this will involve the "path:" option but not sure how to use it

As an example I need to search for a function name "clean" or a test case for "clean" or similar function inside the jquery test suite at the following location - 
https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/test

I understand there are some filters like repo: and path: provided by github but not sure how to use them.

Also I am not satisfied with an answer posted for a similar question at - 
[Search a github repository for the file defining a given function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401923/search-a-github-repository-for-the-file-defining-a-given-function)

I understand I can fork it to my local machine and do a search there but I  don't want to download the whole repository simply to search it. I just need to search it online at the github site itself.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Note sure my answer works well with the new GitHub search engine (https://github.com/blog/1381-a-whole-new-code-search)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I get 41 result with [this query](https://github.com/search?q=repo:hadley/ggplot2%20facet_wrap&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Code&language=R).

The key is to specify the user/reponame, not the the reponame:

```
repo:hadley/ggplot2
```

Combined with **wildcard** for the path argument, I select only *one* argument with [this query](https://github.com/search?q=repo:hadley/ggplot2%20facet_wrap%20path:inst/*.r&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Code&language=R):

```
repo:hadley/ggplot2 facet_wrap path:inst/*.r
```

So, for path, the key is to add a wildcard (which doesn't seem to be documented anywhere).
`path:inst/` alone won't work. `path:*` or `path:*.r` will.

---

From the comments:

> I need to find "`beforeSend`" entry which is in this file - "`jquery / test / unit / ajax.js`" at `github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/test/unit/ajax.js` but when I fire `repo:jeresig/jquery beforeSend path:jquery/test/unit*.js` in the advance search I don't get any results.
> I am also confused which user should I use as jquery has many contributors like John Resig, timmywil

In this case (2012):

- the repo is `jquery/jquery` (no need for a username here)
- the **`path:`** directive to use **must not repeat the repo name**: so, `path:test/unit*.js`, not `path:jquery/test/unit*.js`

```
     repo:jquery/jquery beforeSend path:test/unit*.js
```

will work, and [provide 4 results within JQuery Code](https://github.com/search?q=repo:jquery/jquery%20beforeSend%20path:test/unit*.js&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Code&language=).

Update 2022:

[The query](https://github.com/search?q=beforeSend%20%20repo%3Ajquery%2Fjquery%20path%3A%2Ftest%20extension%3Ajs&type=Code&ref=advsearch&l=&l=) would be:

```
     repo:jquery/jquery beforeSend path:test extension:*js type=Code&ref=advsearch
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I am unable to use it in my scenario of jquery at github. I tried your advice like this - Example - I need to find "beforeSend" entry which is in this file - "jquery / test / unit / ajax.js" at https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/test/unit/ajax.js but when i fire **`repo:jeresig/jquery beforeSend path:jquery/test/unit*.js`** in the advance search I don't get any results. I am also confused which **user** should I use as jquery has many contributors like John Resig, timmywil... etc etc.

Comment: I receive only one result if I remove the "path" **repo:timmywil/jquery beforeSend** but that too is in **jquery / src / ajax.js** and not in **jquery / test / unit / ajax.js** Please suggest if I am doing something wrong. Thanks

Comment: @AnmolSaraf don't repeat `jquery` in the `path:` directive. `path:test/unit*.js` works within a `jquery` repo. This, for instance, works: `https://github.com/search?q=beforeSend++repo%3Ajquery%2Fjquery+path%3Atest%2Funit*.js**&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Code&language=`: that is a search with `beforeSend  repo:jquery/jquery path:test/unit*.js**`. (and I don't see a `repo:jeresig/jquery`: maybe it is a private one?)

Comment: I must say this is replied lightning fast. Thanks so much for the prompt reply. I understood my mistake, actually in my case the username and reponame are the same as "jquery" only. So I had to fire it this way **`repo:jquery/jquery beforeSend path:test/*.js`**  Thanks a tonne once again... You really rock :)

Comment: @AnmolSaraf You are welcome. I have included the jquery example in the answer for other readers.

Comment: FWIW there days it doesn't work with the star for me. `path:docs/` was enough for me.

Comment: @Lyubomir Indeed. I have updated the answer with a query working with the 2022 syntax.