# How to search '.tab-focus()' inside twitter bootstrap repository at github

Tags: file, search, github, directory

This is related to my own question asked at github sometime back at 
[how to search a particular word or entry inside a sub folder in a repository on github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722650/how-to-search-a-particular-word-or-entry-inside-a-sub-folder-in-a-repository-on)

I am trying to apply the same principle this time to search for a function name - .tab-focus() inside bootstrap twitter repository, the entry is in file https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/reset.less at line 51 but just could not search it.

Another entry for the same search word I found is in https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins.less at line 29

I am just not able to search anything with the .less extension files, I don't know why, is github unable to search .less or other less used extension files. I can get search results for .js and .css files but again not .html and .less

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend cloning the project locally and using `git grep`.

```
git clone <repo>
git grep '.tab-focus' *.less
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but I don't want to do it for each and every project, I am just looking for definition of files from anywhere I see a call. I guess previously the answer worked very well with the jquery stuff if you see the link in the question above. Anyway, thanks for answering.

Comment: Gotcha. Yeah, I'd thought I'd mention it because it's a good trick to have when all else fails. I don't like clone a project either unless I must, but even so, when I do, there are some positives to be gained from working with the code locally. Great for project I keep coming back too. Sorry I couldn't help you with the github search.